# Simple Form custom component does not add attribute to input

Tags: ruby-on-rails, simple-form

I want a component that adds 2 things. Firstly, a feedback for the user to see how many characters has left(later updated via JS). Secondly, an attribute(field limit) to the input for the JS to use.

I've followed [this](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/wiki/Adding-custom-components), and pretty much just coping/pasting from [one](https://github.com/plataformatec/simple_form/blob/master/lib/simple_form/components/maxlength.rb) of their built-in components. Feedback is displayed correctly but `:maxlength` is not present at the input.

```
module SimpleForm                                                                                                                                                             
  module Components                                                                                                                                                           
    module CharCounter                                                                                                                                                        
      def char_counter(wrapper_options = nil)                                                                                                                                 
        if options[:char_counter].present?                                                                                                                                    
          input_html_options[:maxlength] = limit                                                                                                                              
          "<span>#{limit - object.read_attribute(attribute_name).length }</span>".html_safe                             
        end                                                                                                                                                                   
      end                                                                                                                                                                     

      def has_char_counter?                                                                                                                                                   
        char_counter.present?                                                                                                                                                 
      end                                                                                                                                                                     
    end                                                                                                                                                                       
  end                                                                                                                                                                         
end
```

wrapper.rb

```
...
b.optional :char_counter, wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block text-right' }
...
```

html output

```
<div class="form-group string required activity_name">
  <label class="string required control-label" for="activity_name">
    Name <abbr title="required">*</abbr>
  </label>
  <input class="string required form-control" type="text" value="" name="activity[name]" id="activity_name">
  <p class="help-block text-right">
    <span>73</span>
  </p>
</div>
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So after a few days of dig through SimpleForm code I realize that
the elements order is quite important

wrapper.rb

```
b.optional :char_counter, wrap_with: { tag: 'p', class: 'help-block text-right' }
```

must be before

```
b.use :input
```